# Find whether Save or cancel button is clicked on print dialog box

Tags: javascript, printing

Hai Guys,
          How to find which button was clicked by the user on a print dialog box.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer has onbeforeprint and onafterprint, but this is browser-specific.

Comment: i want to store it in db, if it is printed else i will ignore it..... Can i use onbeforeprint and onafterprint function

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you don't have access to Application Dialog boxes such as the print dialog. even with events fired by IE.