# How to know click (Ok or Cancel) event from print pop-up of web browser

Tags: c#, javascript

In my application I am printing some data through a pop-up window. On loading the pop-up, the user will be prompted for to either print or cancel. I want to know which button is clicked (print or cancel) so that I can take some action based on the button clicked. The code and screenshot are given below.

```
public void Print(int Id)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = BadgeHelper.preparePrintableString(Id);
            string printWindowFunc = "function printWindow() {\n" +
                                        "var z = window.print();\n alert('Return: ' + z);\n" + 
                                        "checkDocumentState();\n" +
                                      "}";
            string checkDocumentStateFunc = "function checkDocumentState() {\n" +
                                                "if (document.readyState == 'complete') {\n" +
                                                    "window.close();\n" +
                                                "}\n" +
                                                "else {\n alert('Else');\n" +
                                                    "setTimeout('checkDocumentState()', 2000);\n" +
                                                "}\n"+
                                            "}\n";

            string startingHTMLCode = "<html>\n" +
                                        "<head>\n" +
                                            "<script type='text/javascript'>\n " +
                                                checkDocumentStateFunc + 
                                                "\n" +
                                                printWindowFunc +
                                            "</script>\n " + 
                                        "</head>\n" +
                                        "<body onload='printWindow();'>\n";
            sb.Insert(0, startingHTMLCode);
            sb.Append("\n</body>\n</html>");

            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692668/find-whether-save-or-cancel-button-is-clicked-on-print-dialog-box

Comment: Good question, although I think this is 1) not possible from 'fair' js 2) should not really be done (this is my personal hate for too smart and active interfaces).

Comment: `onbeforeprint/onafterprint` doesn't allow to check printing status, as well as return result of `window.print`.

Comment: As a side-note, you should never put your javascript in C# code like this, it's an anti-pattern. This question has absolutely nothing to do with C#.